# Colgroup borders in nested table

Tags: html, css, nested-table

I am looking for a way to build my own version of http://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/

HTML & CSS:

```css
 table {
   width: 100%;
   table-layout: fixed;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border-spacing: 0;
   font-size: 1em;
   border: 1px solid;
   border-color: grey;
 }
 tr {
   border-color: grey;
 }
 col {
   display: table-column;
   border: 1px solid;
 }
 .table-container {
   width: 800px;
   height: 600px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td width="200px"></td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <colgroup>
              <col style="width: 119.4px"></col>
              <col style="width: 119.4px"></col>
              <col style="width: 119.4px"></col>
              <col style="width: 119.4px"></col>
              <col style="width: 119.4px"></col>
            </colgroup>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="chrono">
                <th>1am</th>
                <th>2am</th>
                <th>3am</th>
                <th>4am</th>
                <th>5am</th>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="200px">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Schicht 1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Schicht 2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Schicht 3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Schicht 4</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Schicht 5</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Schicht 6</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="event-container" style="height: 22.5px"></div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="event-container" style="height: 22.5px"></div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="event-container" style="height: 22.5px"></div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="event-container" style="height: 22.5px"></div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="event-container" style="height: 22.5px"></div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="event-container" style="height: 22.5px"></div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Currently i am constructing the table: https://jsfiddle.net/qh75ksze/

I have some problems creating the grid like look in the bottom right field. I have my rows and i kind of want the column borders run through them as seen in the first link. Is there any way to do it as i can't figure out how they did it on the website. Thanks

Comment: I guess you misknow how to build a table , first colgroup applies only to the table it belongs to, then why do you insert table within each cells , all datas suppose to be on your visual rows  will be disconnected ?? colgroup:https://jsfiddle.net/qh75ksze/1/ for the table structure itself, you need to explain us the reason, or find some tutorials how to build a table and rethink your actual structure

Comment: I am just copying the table on the site. And wonder how they do it that their column borders appear also in the nested tables. The columns borders in the <thead> of the outmost table here http://fullcalendar.io/ reach all the way down through the rows of the nested tables. I wonder how?

Comment: looks to me like a background grid